# pandas replace all values of a column with a column values that increment by n starting at 0

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe like so that I have read in from a file (note: *.ene is a txt file)

```
df = pd.read_fwf('filename.ene')
TS     DENSITY     STATS
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

I would like to only change the TS column. I wish to replace all the column values of 'TS' with the values from range(0,751,125). The desired output should look like so:

```
TS     DENSITY     STATS
0
125
250
500
625
750
```

I'm a bit lost and would like some insight regarding the code to do such a thing in a general format.
I used a for loop to store the values into a list:

```
K=(6*125)+1 
m = []
for i in range(0,K,125):
    m.append(i)
```

I thought to use .replace like so:

```
df['TS']=df['TS'].replace(old_value, m, inplace=True)
```

but was not sure what to put in place of old_value to select all the values of the 'TS' column or if this would even work as a method.

Comment: did you try `df['TF']=range(0,K,125)`?

Comment: I did - and it didn't work :/ However, when I print(m) the list prints out correctly. when i do print(df['TS']) it still prints out the original column

Comment: Your problem is the length of both lists, `df['TS']` has length 6, while m has length 7, because in the desired output you forgot that: `list(range(0,K,125))=[0, 125, 250, 375, 500, 625, 750]`, you forgot the 375 value in your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty straight forward, if you're replacing all the data you just need to do

```
df['TS'] =m
```

example :

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0, 1, 2], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(df)
#    a   b   c
# 0  10  20  30
# 1  40  50  60
# 2  70  80  90

df['a'] = [1,2,3]
print(df)
#    a   b   c
# 0  1  20  30
# 1  2  50  60
# 2  3  80  90
```